# Import public/private ECDH keys in BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, private, bouncycastle, public, ecdh

I'm trying to import public and private ECDH keys in BouncyCastle. To import public key i use the C# code bellow and the code is works fine:

```
byte[] pc = HexStringToByteArray(PUBLIC_KEY);
var ecdp = TlsEccUtilities.GetParametersForNamedCurve(NamedCurve.secp256r1);
var basePoint = TlsEccUtilities.ValidateECPublicKey(TlsEccUtilities.DeserializeECPublicKey(null, ecdp, pc));
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subinfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(basePoint);
ECPublicKeyParameters publicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(subinfo);
```

**public key:**
042e3e5ccf6b9ab04be7a22f3faccfde73c87e87155394a34815408a896ca18a374dac669af3bf6220fc863767f4af47507c5bc221fc4a19874daf39b4074e3eb8

**private key:**
be3f9bff87973356d04dad279e21535925c3656db011c9ae76b5a7f09ef8d9de

But i can't find a solution to import the private key. Colud you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finlay i found a solution:

```
// Import public key
byte[] pc = HexStringToByteArray(PUBLIC_KEY);
var ecdp = TlsEccUtilities.GetParametersForNamedCurve(NamedCurve.secp256r1);
var basePoint = TlsEccUtilities.ValidateECPublicKey(TlsEccUtilities.DeserializeECPublicKey(null, ecdp, pc));
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subinfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(basePoint);
ECPublicKeyParameters publicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(subinfo);

// Import private key
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(HexStringToByteArray(PRIVATE_KEY));
ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKey = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(bi, publicKey.Parameters);
```